# Update label + 1 Per Web browser Refresh at a specific time using c#

Tags: c#

my question is how can i update label + 1 per web browser refresh at a specific time using c#,

- I want to be able to set my timer through textbox..
- I want the web browser to refresh after the the time i set through my textbox in the timer has exceed..
- And once the web browser is refresh, i want it to a + 1 to my label (example i set my label to 0 so once a url is refresh it should change to 1, one refresh two time the label should be 2 and so on)...
- I want to be able to stop the timer...

please how can i achieve these in c#....Thanks very much

Note : It is a Window form Application...Thanks

Comment: Which technology used for the website ? aps.net or MVC

Comment: Event trigger if url refresh -> label++

Comment: @RageshS...i just want to reload any url....it might even be www.google.com

Comment: @RageshS note it is a window form application

Comment: @Hubii..can u drop full code

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is unfortunately impossible, since you want to manipulate a different application from your application.

What you could do is implement a `WebBrowser` control in your forms application, which renders a browser in your application.
This browser *can* be manipulated by you. Refresh by using `webBrowser1.Refresh();`. (Where `webBrowser1` is the name of your webbrowser control.)

See the following documentation on webbrowser controls: 
[Webbrowser controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms)

Comment: it not from different application,,,it.s the webbrowser control

Comment: If it's a webbrowser control, above mentioned `.Refresh` function should work. Did you try this?